# Нормально ли когда столько запросов?

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте, подскажите, нормально ли когда идет столько запросов к бд? Можно ли как-то в пачку одним запросом ?
[image: Скриншот запросов]
Связь многие ко многим.

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'recipe_tags');
}

@foreach($recipes as $recipe)
   @foreach ($recipe->tags as $tag){{$tag->name }} //запросы идут из-за получения тегов рецепта.

   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) для получения $recipes

```
$recipes = Recipe::with('tags')->...->get();
```

или

```
$recipes = Recipe::...->get()->load('tags');
```

Comment: Спасибо именно так и сделал в тот же вечер.